# Require .csproj nuget packages to exist when building solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I'm creating an app to automatically update nuget packages in a solution and build it to be sure they are still compatible.

Scenario:

`<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.5" />`
Clean/Build package with correct package version. It Succeeds.

Then I edit the version in the .csproj with garbage text.

`<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="dasdasdasdqw3" />`
It still succeeds. However it does log the error:
 `Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Invalid restore input. Missing required property 'Name'.`

My understanding is that it is using the previous successful version from the `\.nuget\packages` folder.

Is there a way to have the build fail if the package could not be restored that does not involve deleting it from `\.nuget\packages`?

Comment: Is there a warning or error code associated with that message? My guess is that that _error_ is actually a warning

Comment: Did you use a non-sdk net framework project with packagereference or a new sdk net core project with packagereference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you used a **net core** project.

**First**, make sure that you have enabled these two options under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**General**:

[image]

**Actually**, when you change the version, vs will detect the change and use the current version and will not used the latest valid package under `\.nuget\packages`. In my side, it failed.

**Right-click** on your project **Properties**-->**Unload project**-->**Edit Project File** and then change from `1.50.5` to `adadd`. And then reload your project, you will find that the project has an invalid nuget version called `asda`.

It fails build process successfully. You should click **Rebuild** rather than **Build** button.

[image]

**========**

If you did not see the nuget package version displayed UI under **solution explorer**, you could unload the project and then reload your project. And wait for a moment to get the change.

**Besides**, you could add `dotnet restore` command under Project **Properties**-->**Build Events**-->**Pre-Build event command line** to make it more accurately.

To use the latest updated version automatically, you could use [Floating Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#floating-versions).

Try this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="*" />
```

It will update the nuget package to use the latest version under nuget package source feed rather than the latest version from cache `\.nuget\packages`. When you reload your project, wait for a moment, and you will see the change to use the latest nuget version automatically.

Comment: Thank you for this write up. Using the restore parameter for msbuild worked for me.